# Does it matter which orb I take in "Ghost in the Machine"?

Tags: saints-row-iv

In "Ghost in the Machine", you steal an orb for the AI to use. When it comes time to take one, there are five to choose from. Kinzie says, "It doesn't matter. Just pick one."

If it doesn't matter, why bother with the choice? If it does matter, what are the differences between the choices?

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't matter.

If the experience is the same each time, the first two explode and the third one works fine.

You pick one; it blows up and you need to pick from the remaining four. You pick a second; it blows up and you need to pick from the remaining three. (All the while being ridiculed from Kinzie.) The third pick will work out fine.

Comment: The math isn't adding up here.  The question says there are 5 to choose from but the answer mentions 3.

Comment: I've not gotten to this part of the game, but I think what patridge is trying to say is that the first 2 you pick up explode - no matter which 2 you pick up - and that your third choice works.

Comment: I tried to clear up the confusion with a better description of the process.

Comment: My experience was the same as partridge's.  I did somewhat speculate that it wasn't fixed at 3 and is one at random out of the five, but I think the point of this scene is to show that you break stuff when you touch it, so a scripted sequence of three makes more sense so that players always have the same experience.  The statement by Kinzie of "it doesn't matter. Just pick one" is meant as a tongue in cheek joke that the *programmer nerd* could have done it with any of them, but the *hamfisted brute* (you) takes three attempts.

Comment: I can confirm this. I've experienced the same thing on three different playthroughs of the mission (regardless of which order I select the orbs/CIDs).